What is the 'easiest' coordinate system for categorizing points on a sphere according to the following rule?
I am in 3D space. I have a collection of unit vectors (with all positive Cartesian coordinates) that I would like to categorize in 7 sections (see the diagram below). By 'categorize', I mean I want to code a decision rule that, given the vector in Cartesian coordinates, outputs the category it is in.
I have attempted to describe the areas using Cartesian and spherical coordinates. However, I get stuck quite quickly as some of the areas are straightforward, while others are more complicated equations.
What is key to a good answer is to have an quick algorithm for the categorization, hence ideally the need for rectangular partitioning of a coordinate space, or at most linear.
Here is the desired classification:
classification
The classifications are create from only a handful of points:

The edges are created by drawing an arc of radius 0.5* at $h = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, where $h$ is the axes whose corner is being drawn.
The center is created by drawing a circle from points $(0.5,0.5,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, $(0.5,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0.5)$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0.5,0.5)$
The last segments to define E, F and G are drawn using points $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}})$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}})$

My intuition tells me that I should be augmenting the 2D surface to a 3D coordinate space, so that we have more flexibility. Maybe define axes in the direction of the segments between E, F and G?
Any help would be appreciated!
* Edit 1: from radius 1 to radius 0.5

maybe project the points to a simplex by dividing by $x+y+z$ and then treating the 2d problem of points on a triangle?

Idk if its a simplex space... we are still on the unit sphere. So its already a 2D area. Thoughts?

I think that by removing one coordinate, and finding the relevant equations for the boundaries, you are left with the problem of determining where each 2d point lies wrt to each. curve (in, out, left. right etc)

When you say "arc of radius 1", do you mean a "great circle"?

That is my mistake: it should be radius 0.5. I will edit**

I haven't checked whether any of the separating curves that look to lie in a plane actually do, but your life would be easy if

$A = \{x \gt c\}$, for some value $c$.
Similar for $B$ and $C$, using $z$ and $y$.
Your circle $D$ were given by $\{x+y+z \gt d\}$ for some $d$.
And each of the last three areas seem to be distinguished from each other by each lying in the intersection of two half-planes picked from the separations given by $\{x\lessgtr y\}$, $\{y\lessgtr z\}$, and $\{z\lessgtr x\}$.


Edited to add: Perhaps an easier way to think about distinguishing between the last three regions, E, F, and G, is that they each correspond to different answers to "which co-ordinate is smaller than the other two co-ordinates?". E.g. region F = $\{z \lt x \text{ and } z \lt y\}$.

Yes you are right: planes will correctly distinguish A, B, C and D. The remaining require two planes. Thanks!

@MarcoFroelich - Glad it helps. I've added a note on what I think is a simpler way to thing about regions E, F, and G. It probably doesn't change the decision code one would come up with, but might make it easier to think/reason about.
